# How to install tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu with AMD Radeon R4/R5 graphics cards

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, amd-gpu

Here is the output from `tensorflow` import:

```
File "/home/shashi/libs/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic return _load(spec) 
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you verify that the libcuda.so file exists?

Answer (score 0):

The GPU accelerated versions of Tensorflow only support CUDA acceleration. That means it only works on Nvidia hardware. It is not going to work on AMD GPUs. There is an open issue in the tensorflow bug tracker to add support for OpenCL acceleration. [You can track the progress here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22)